# How to run a Spark test from IntelliJ (or other IDE)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, gradle, kerberos

I am trying to create a Test for some Spark code. The following code fails when getting a SparkSession object. NOTE: The test runs fine when running from the cli: gradle my_module:build

```
@Test
def myTest(): Unit = {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
  ...
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get Kerberos realm
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm
```

My set-up: IntelliJ + Gradle + Mac OS

Questions:

- How do I run a Spark Test from within IntelliJ?
- Why is Spark looking for Kerberos at all when running 'local'

Comment: _"Why is Spark looking for Kerberos at all when running 'local'"_ -- Spark always bootstraps a Hadoop `Configuration`; if the Hadoop client finds a valid `core-site.xml` in the CLASSPATH (depending on `HADOOP_HOME` and/or `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and/or `spark.driver.extraClassPath`) then you may end up with a default filesystem set to HDFS with Kerberos auth! Lacking actual conf files, the Hadoop client will revert to hard-coded defaults i.e. local filesystem and no Kerberos.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter this is a really really helpful note. We get kerberos auth failures for most devs using intellij on windows, but mine somehow work on mac/osx. What's really weird is the windows machines run the same tests fine from gradle/command line. Hopefully this information you've provided will help me track down the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lo-Tan > if it is a Windows-specific issue _**and**_ you see warnings about `native libraries` then maybe setting `java.library.path` to `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` could be used as a workaround -- or at least lead to a more meaningful exception. Cf. https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html while remembering that the PATH is the default place where Windows looks for DLL (just like LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the default place where Linux looks for .so dynamic link libs)

Answer (score 0):

By your code you need to run Spark from JUnit, not specifically from IntelliJ, you can try something like https://github.com/sleberknight/sparkjava-testing